# Kotlin equivalent of class properties, constructors, empty parameter constructors, getters and setters

Tags: kotlin

I am currently practicing in developing kotlin and as of now I seem to get confused with kotlin's class structure.

this is a code in java

```
 //properties
    private String var;

    //constructor
    public SampleClass(String var){
        this.var = var;
    }

    public SampleClass(){
    }

    //getters and setters
    public String getVar(){
        return this.var;
    }
    public String setVar(String var){
        this.var = var;
    }
```

what's the kotlin equivalent of this ?

Comment: read: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: Nice you're starting with kotlin. There is kind of an online tutorial at https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Hello,%20world!/Task.kt. ALso I can recommend the book "Android for Kotlin Developers" by Antonio Leiva. It got me started on Android/Kotlin developement.

Comment: @JaysonMinard I just really get confused with the constructor, the one with the init block, and the secondary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the equivalent Kotlin code for your Java code:

```
class SampleClass(var `var`: String? = null)
```

There are a few things to note:

1. Your Java snippet above omits the wrapping `class SampleClass` code
2. Your `setVar()` indicates that it returns a `String`, but it's actually `void`. I assume you intended for it to have a `void` return type.
3. Your property `var` is not ideal for Kotlin, because it's a reserved word. That's why we have to escape it with backticks. (It could also be kind of confusing in Java 10, since `var` is a reserved type name there now).

Here's why this one-liner is equivalent to the Java listing.

1. The [constructor](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) part - the part between the parentheses - can be used to accept constructor arguments, but by putting the Kotlin keyword `var` at the beginning, we tell Kotlin that we want this to also be a *property*.  Kotlin will create a getter and setter for it.
2. The `String?` part makes this property of type [nullable](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types) String.
3. Instead of creating two different constructors, we just give our `var` property argument a [default value](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) of `null` by using `= null`. When creating this class from Java, it'll still show up as two constructors.

If you're using IntelliJ or Android Studio, you can tell it to convert any Java class to Kotlin.  Just open the class file, and go to the `Code` menu, and choose `Convert Java file to Kotlin file`.  It won't necessarily generate very idiomatic code (e.g., it might create two constructors instead of using a default for the constructor argument), but it'll get you started.

Comment: so it's only one line ?

Comment: @ronan you can also keep the constructors separate, look up "secondary constructors" in the Kotlin docs for how to make another.  If you need it for a different case.

Comment: @ronan Yes, in this case, the equivalent Kotlin code is just one line. There are multiple ways that you could write it, of course, but this is the most concise, so most Kotlin programmers would start with this until something more elaborate is needed.

Comment: Thank you! this helped me understand it more

Answer (score 0):

For "what is Kotlin equivalent of some code in Java", there is an universal answer: copy the Java code and paste it into a Kotlin file in IDEA/Android Studio. Or [convert the entire file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html).

On the web, you can use https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt.